# Display all data from couchDb with knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm able to display one **row** into `myField` but i want to loop through all rows.
I want to display all names in a formatted text in html. i think something with **for-each** in my HTML View, but im really stuck here.

My JSON from couchDB looks like this:

```
{"total_rows":8,"offset":0,"rows":[
 {"id":"f1abbf3ccb0f15d6a66f7eadab003f53","key":"AccessBareBoneApp","value":{"Properties":{"Properties":[]},"Implements":{"Interfaces":[{"TypeName":"ITSR2.Bricks.Access.IAccessBareBoneBrick"},{"TypeName":"ITSR2.Bricks.Access.IAccessAppBrick"}]},"Name":"AccessBareBoneApp","Description":"","TypeName":"ITSR2.Bricks.Access.AccessBareBoneApp","AssemblyName":"ITSR2.Bricks.MSOffice, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","Obsolete":false}},
```

My **main.js** file:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.myfield =  ko.observableArray([]);

}

var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/helloworld');

var vm = new ViewModel();

db.query("bricksetup/docs").then(function(result) { 
  var data = result;
  console.log(data);
  data.rows.forEach(function(row){
      vm.data.push(row.value)
  // vm.myfield(data.rows[3].value.Name);
 // vm.myfield2(data.rows[2].value.Name);
  })
   vm.myfield(data.rows[3].value.Name);
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

My **index.html**:

```
      <h3>Brick Infos</h3>
       <div data-bind="">
         <p> 
            <b>Name:</b>
            <span data-bind="text:myfield"></span>
            <b>Description:</b>

            <span data-bind=></span>
            <b>TypeName:</b>
            <span data-bind=></span>
            <b>AssemblyName</b>
            <span data-bind=></span>
            <b>Obsolete</b>
            <span data-bind=></span>
          </p>
          <p data-bind=>
          <b>Name:</b>
            <span data-bind=></span> |
          <b>Validation Type:</b>
            <span data-bind=></span><br>
          </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the `data.rows` to your variable `myField` like this `vm.myfield(data.rows);` . Place it under your `console.log` and remove the forEach Loop.

And on Index.html:

`<div data-bind="foreach:myfield">`
`<span data-bind="text:value.Name"></span>`
`</div`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more work on the Javascript side and assuming there is going to be more than one row then assign that to a ko.observableArray. Is that what `self.myfield` is for?

Assuming yes, then set up the self.myfield using something like `self.myfield(data.rows)`. nice and simple and no need for all that pushing!

On the HTML side, for each row you need a data-bind e.g.

`<h3>Brick Infos</h3>
       <div data-bind="foreach: self.myfield">`

I think this will work - I use ES6 Javascript so I don't have to use self = this, I would just use `foreach: myfield`

The rest of the html is not using proper data-bind syntax.  Each field would need something like `<p><span class="title">Field Title</span><span class=text data-bind="text: data.fieldName"></span></p>`

Then create a css class to highlight the title and replace Field Title with whatever you want to appear to the user as the title of the field, and replace Fieldname with the relevant fieldname e.g. Name, Description, TypeName etc.

Note items which which have multiple values possible such as Implements.Interfaces use `data-bind=:foreach data.Implements.Interfaces` to repeat those items if needed on the page.

Comment: You can't display the values from nested items with that `data-bind="foreach: data.Implements.Interfaces"`

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing into `vm.data`, but the observableArray field is `myfield`. Then you're setting the value of the observableArray to the Name field of one data item. That's a very confused approach.

It looks like your query is going to come back with a result that contains `rows`, which are (more or less) what you want in your array.

```
db.query("bricksetup/docs").then(function(result) { 
  vm.myfield(result.rows);
});
```

It also looks like each row has a `value` object, and the fields you're interested in are inside that.

```
  <h3>Brick Infos</h3>
  <div data-bind="foreach:myfield">
      <b>Name:</b>
      <span data-bind="text:value.Name"></span>
  </div>
```

This should get you started with the fewest lines of code. You'll probably want to re-map the rows to just put the value object into myfield.

Comment: I get an Error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: vm.myField is not a function(…)` .

Comment: There is not a capital F in `myfield`. I provided the same code as the answer you accepted.